# Refresh Button in java

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt

I need to make a simple refresh button  for a gui java program I have the button made but its not working properly. I just am not sure what the code needs to be to make the button work. Any help would be really appreciated.I figured the code below
`

```
 refeshButton.addListener(new ButtonListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Button button, EventObject e) {
                // Window.alert("text" + button.getText());

                if (button.getText().equals("Refresh")) {
                    sendDataToServ1("Refresh");
                }
            }

            public void sendDataToServ1(String action) {
                System.out.println("ACTION :----->" + action);

                AsyncCallback<com.viji.example.domain.Record> callback = new AsyncCallback<com.viji.example.domain.Record>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

                        System.out.println("Failure");
                    }

                    public void onSuccess(com.viji.example.domain.Record result) {

                        CompanySampledetails(result, 1);

                    }

                };

                if (action.trim().equals("Refresh")) {
                    System.out.println("Before Refresh");

                    dbService.getRecords(callback);

                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not working properly? It helps if you remove all the code not central to your problem, makes it that much more easier to scan and to point any errors.

Comment: I want to display the refreshed values whenever I clicked the refresh button. But now I click the refresh button its not display the changed content in my window , the old values are displayed.

Comment: How do you create a dbService instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Warning: The local variable `buttonClickListener` is never read.*

After you create it, try saying `refeshButton.addListener(buttonClickListener);`

---

**Edit:**

The method `sendDataToServ(String action)` never references its parameter.  This is the method called by your listener.  Did you mean to call `sendDataToServer(String action)` instead?  If that's the case, it does practically nothing with its parameter either.  All it does it tests `action` against the string "Add".

You should try tossing around a liberal amount of logging statements.

Comment: I tried it also.... But its not working.



refeshButton.addListener(new ButtonListenerAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(Button button, EventObject e) {
    // Window.alert("text" + button.getText());

    if (button.getText().equals("Refresh")) {
     sendDataToServ("Refresh");
    }
   }
  });